# Can't use default colors inside extendTheme (ChakraUI)

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm trying to do this:

```
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import Fonts from "./Fonts";

const theme = extendTheme({
  fonts: {
    logo: "Satisfy",
  },
  colors: {
    main: {
      500: "red.500",
    },
  },
});
```

but when using it like this it doesn't work(main.500 is not recognized):

```
function Logo() {
  return (
    <Center as={(props) => <Link {...props} to="/" />} h="full" p="10">
      <Heading
        fontFamily="logo"
        as="h1"
        fontSize="4xl"
        fontWeight="bold"
        color="main.500"
      >
        My Recipes
      </Heading>
    </Center>
  );
}
```

What is the correct approach? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to use the default colors:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import theme, { Theme } from "@chakra-ui/theme";
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";

import Chakra from "./Test-Chakra.js"

export default function App() {
const theme = extendTheme({
  fonts: {
    logo: "Satisfy",
  },
  colors: {
    main: {
      500: "#00dd00",
      900: "#dd3333",
    },
  },
})

return (
    <>
      <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
        <Chakra />
      </ChakraProvider>
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Test-Chakra.js - using this code you can now change the color to main.500 (custom color) or red.500 (default color) as you wish.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Center, Heading } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import theme, { Theme } from "@chakra-ui/theme"

export default function Chakra(props) {

return (
<>
    <Center >
      <Heading
        fontFamily="logo"
        as="h1"
        fontSize="4xl"
        fontWeight="bold"
        color="red.500" 
      >
        My Recipes
      </Heading>
    </Center>
</>
  );
}
```

Comment: I know I can just use the color code. but I want to use the colors with their names from the default chakraui theme.

Comment: Ok, I added some code to show you how it works.